# How to remove the black bars with Openshot

Tags: video, video-editor, openshot

I downloaded a video from YouTube with Openshot, then I cut little portions of it with the same program. The aspect ratio of the video originally a 16:9) was changed and 4 big black bars were added (2 on the top, 2 at the bottom). I can see the video well, it's not distorted, nor anything like that, but there are these huge black bars. I looked a lot around for solutions, but there doesn't seem to be a good way to remove them. The only solution which I seem to find (in different places) is the one proposed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TUZX4Oa2yq0 however, it just moves the video around (I tried in different ways), but Openshot doesn't seem to remove the black bars.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the preview, then the black bars will only show up there. Black bars are ONLY added when viewing a video at the wrong resolution, to fill space. You will need to look at your original aspect ratio, and export it at that ratio ONLY.

EDIT: It looks like you need to crop the video:
Right click on the clip in the bottom bar, and select "properties." Select the "Layout" tab and edit the **Height** and **Width** values. Then, move the video around with **x** and **y**. Do not touch Alpha. Press the green play button to preview your clip. You want to increase the zoom, and move the video around until the black bars no longer appear...HOWEVER, on the small preview, there will be bars on the top and bottom that will not appear in post. Hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I'm not talking about the preview. I'm talking about this video on YouTube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4BouRFKfJc As you can see it has sobe black bars, but it's not that bad. When I cut it using VideoShot, though, big, huge black bars are added on top and at the bottom, on the right and on the left. It's very easy to remove those bars using VirtualDub on Windows, like you can see in this video (starting at 1:16 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-BcFcfh4KVc I was wondering if there was something similar on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm sorry. Seeing the video, I realized that the bars were embedded in the video itself. I'll edit the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you. However it's a painstaking process of trial and error and in the end it doesn't really work very well. I really wish there was something as simple as VirtualDub, where you just see the black bars covered while you're doing it.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only way to do it with OpenShot as far as I know. Sorry. I use it myself and find it difficult to use and a bit lacking in features, or moreso in the ease of use of common features (e.g captions). Sadly, most other Linux video editors are also difficult. However, I do know that you can crop videos in youtube by going into the video manager, selecting Edit on the video you want, going to Enhancements and selecting the Trim button next to the pair of scissors.

Answer (score 0):

Select a profile for the project that exactly matches your source video resolution. If none of the available ones matches your video, you can add a custom one: https://cdn.openshot.org/static/files/user-guide/profiles.html#custom-profile

In my case, I used the template on the page I linked to (1080p), and changed the resolution to 1920x1200, and the aspect to 16:10. That worked perfectly.